# Разделитель групп разрядов чисел

Tags: php, smarty

В панели поиска в поле метраж добавить разделитель групп разрядов.

Сейчас в поле метраж при наборе 10000, отображается: 10000

Нужно чтобы вместо 10000 отображалось в формате: 10 000.

Есть в этой же панели поиска сейчас поле ввода цены, здесь правильно выводит формат вывода чисел, т.е. сейчас в поле цена если вводишь 10000 то отображается 10 000. Это код поля вывода цены:

```
<input type="text" class="price_from price_field" name="price_min" value="{if isset($price_min)}{$price_min|number_format:0:'':' '}{else}0{/if}"/>
```

Есть поле ввода метража, хочу изменить формат вывода чисел. Сейчас в поле метраж при наборе 10000, отображается: 10000:   (2я строчка кода (ниже) - это поля метраж без изменений)

```
<input type="text" name="square_max" value="{if (isset($smarty.request.square_max) && $smarty.request.square_max!=0)}{$smarty.request.square_max}{/if}" />
```

В 3й строчке кода (ниже) исправил код для вывода метража, т.е. это та же вторая строчка кода выше, только добавил `|number_format:0:'':' '` (**но не выводит в нужном формате** также при наборе 10000, отображается: 10000):

```
<input type="text" name="square_max" value="{if (isset($smarty.request.square_max) && $smarty.request.square_max!=0)}{$smarty.request.square_max|number_format:0:'':' '}{/if}" />
```

Применил по аналогии как в поле вывода цены (1я строчка кода), где всё работает.

Comment: а в каком выводит? зы: уберите свои `isset`,  не нужны они.

Comment: @teran  Первая строчка кода выводит правильно формат чисел (для поля вывода цены). Вторая строчка кода (без исправлений, то что хочу изменить) для поля вывода площади (тут изначально были isset). Третья строчка кода - эта та же вторая строчка кода, только добавил |number_format:0:'':' ' из первой строчки кода, где правильно выводится поле вывода цены.

Comment: это я и из вопроса понял. Вы пишите, что выводит неправильно. то есть вместо `10 000` выводится что-то иное. что именно. без разделителя, или что происходит?

Comment: @teran  Сейчас отображается в поле метраж (2 строчка кода): 10000.

Нужно чтобы вместо 10000 отображалось 10 000 (попробовал это сделать в 3 строчке кода).

Comment: у вас шаблоны вообще на другие изменения верстки реагируют?  Код в целом нужный, работать должно. Так что либо вы правите не тот шаблон, либо изменения не применяются (отключена проверка таймштампов изменения (что делается на рабочем сайте))

Comment: папку компиляции шаблонов очистите на всякий случай и опкэш скиньте, если включен.

Comment: @teran  на другие изменения верстки реагируют.  Попробую другие ваши рекомендации.